# Monitor Flickering caused by repeating gif image

Tags: display, physical-damage, burn-in

I have an LG LED IPS monitor (22MP55). A GIF image of an animated firefly flapping its wings was on my screen and I was doing something else with my laptop and didn't notice monitor. After 15 minutes that I came back and closed the GIF image, I found that  some parts of my monitor (Where firefly flapped its wings) flicker like the firefly wing flap pattern.

Is there any hope for it to get better? Should I turn it off for some time? Is there any software solution for this?

If you are curious see what was the firefly, it is an static image of it. you can imagine this flapping its wings up and down at a 30 degree range at a rate of 10 times per second. (10Hz) (Actual GIF Was too large to upload here)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, power-cycle your computer & screen, just in case it's that simple.

A common trick to ease burn-in on many screen types, from CRT to plasma & beyond is to play a non-static image over either the entire screen or the area with the issue.
There are apps that purport to free up stuck pixels etc, but really just playing a regular TV channel is often sufficient.
The simplest way to do this these days if you don't have a built-in tuner is to set up YouTube & have it play some random selection of anything - TV shows, pop videos - & let it run full-screen for several hours or overnight if the screen isn't going to disturb your sleep.